# InfluxDB: query aggregations but deal with missing data

Tags: influxdb

In InfluxDB I want to query our dataset for aggregations.
Usually our sensor send data every 30 minutes.
We can get values like mean per hour etc.
IN some occasions, we might mis a few hours of data. We want influx to keep taking the last value for these 'missing'  steps to calculate the aggregation.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `fill` option in your time grouping. I would say `previous` is the option, which you want:

> previous  Reports the value from the previous time interval for time intervals with no data.

https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/data_exploration/#group-by-time-intervals-and-fill

Comment: Great, just overlooked that. In flux there is   |> fill(usePrevious: true), but not much options do do linear etc. Is it?
Anyway,   |> fill(usePrevious: true) is helping me out just fine now.